# for in loop keeps running firebase database swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have the following code to retreive data from my firebase database:

```
ref = Database.database().reference().child("data").child("someData")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

        for child in snapshot.children {
            let someSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
            self.someArray.append(someSnap.key)
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
```

This code succesfully appends the 4 string elements i have in my database to the array in my viewcontroller class, however it does so over and over again. The array keeps growing with hundreds of strings of the same 4 items over and over. How can I get only the 4 items I want?

Comment: There are a few answer guesses that may be correct, and the question is closed as the code IN the question will not cause that issue. That means there's additional code involved. Are you repeatedly calling the code in the question from another section of code? Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as we need Complete and Minimal code to duplicate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you call the function many times , so make sure to clear it

```
self.someArray.removeAll()
for child in snapshot.children {
    let someSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
    self.someArray.append(someSnap.key)
}
self.collectionView?.reloadData()
```

Comment: Correct, I was calling the function multiple different places... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As from your question, you are calling function many times, when you call function again remove all elements from array or clear array and reload your collection view so it does not add same items again. As updated your code:

```
ref = Database.database().reference().child("data").child("someData")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        self.someArray.removeAll()
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let someSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
            self.someArray.append(someSnap.key)

        }
      self.collectionView?.reloadData()
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have access to the database I'd suggest you use the debugger over the for loop and trace it step by step and checking for the values in each iteration to see what exactly you're appending to the array